# Spring: How to get the model attribute and check if it is null in JSP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp, jstl

I just start to learn Spring framework recently. In my controller, I write

```
@GetMapping("/users/{username}")
public String getUserByUsername(@PathVariable(value = "username") String username, ModelMap model) {
    User founduser = userRepository.findById(username)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "username", username));

    model.addAttribute("founduser",founduser);
    return "redirect:/profile";
}
```

Then, I try to get the model attribute and print it in my JSP.

```
 <c:when test="${not empty founduser}">
             <table style="border: 1px solid;">
                <c:forEach var="one" items="${founduser}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${one.username}</td>

                        <td>${one.createdAt}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </c:when>
```

However, I found that the test="${not empty founduser} is always false, which mean my founduser attribute is null. When I debug, it shows that the model adds the founduser successfully.

Who can tell me why I got error? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `${not empty founduser}` will access values from the current request attribute only.

However you use `redirect:/profile` to display JSP .Redirect means another new request will be send to server. This new request will not go through `getUserByUsername` controller and hence there are no `founduser` in this new request attribute and JSP cannot find it.

To solve it , depending on your application architecture , you can

1. Do not redirect in your controller , just return `profile`.
2. If you really need to redirect , add the values to the flash attribute such that they can still be survived and accessed after redirect:

   `model.addFlashAttribute("founduser",founduser);`